# DNS resolving problem after upgrading to 17.10

Tags: networking, 17.10, dns, systemd-resolved

After upgrading to 17.10, Ubuntu is using systemd-resolved to handle all DNS requests, and it has a stub listener, but the listener only accept requests from local. I am using a Vultr VPS, this is what happened.

```
root@00:~# nslookup www.google.com 127.0.0.53
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

** server can't find www.google.com: SERVFAIL
```

In the errlog:

```
Dec 19 01:20:24 00.tokyo.jp.mole systemd-resolved[684]: Got packet on unexpected IP range, refusing.
```

I tried to dump the udp package and here is the result:

```
root@00:~# tcpdump -i lo udp port 53 -vv -X
tcpdump: listening on lo, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
01:20:24.230349 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 24187, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 60)
    45.xx.xx.xx.vultr.com.60360 > 127.0.0.53.domain: [bad udp cksum 0xbf8c -> 0xe032!] 58738+ A? www.google.com. (32)
    0x0000:  4500 003c 5e7b 0000 4011 5ce3 2dxx xxxx  E..<^{..@.\.-...
    0x0010:  7f00 0035 ebc8 0035 0028 bf8c e572 0100  ...5...5.(...r..
    0x0020:  0001 0000 0000 0000 0377 7777 0667 6f6f  .........www.goo
    0x0030:  676c 6503 636f 6d00 0001 0001            gle.com.....
01:20:24.230963 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 25931, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 40)
    127.0.0.53.domain > localhost.60360: [bad udp cksum 0xfe5b -> 0xae9c!] 58738 ServFail [0q] 0/0/0 (12)
    0x0000:  4500 0028 654b 4000 4011 d743 7f00 0035  E..(eK@.@..C...5
    0x0010:  7f00 0001 0035 ebc8 0014 fe5b e572 8182  .....5.....[.r..
    0x0020:  0000 0000 0000 0000                      ........
```

It shows that it is sending the request using the public IP instead of 127.0.0.1, so systemd-resolved refuse to reply. Using `systemd-resolve www.google.com` could get the result and it shows that the service is functioning normally.

```
root@00:~# systemd-resolve www.google.com
www.google.com: 216.58.196.228
                2404:6800:400a:806::2004

-- Information acquired via protocol DNS in 6.6ms.
-- Data is authenticated: no
```

I temporarily changed the symlink of `/etc/resolv.conf` to `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` so the server could have access to the Internet, but I want to know how can I change the requesting IP to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had the same problem with an upgraded Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04 server.
My solution was to check my firewall settings and exclude the loopback device `lo` from masquerading the source IPs (D'oh!).

Be sure to check your routes and your firewall routing magic like POSTROUTING { MASQUERADE; }. It was working before since the old DNS resolver wasn't as picky with source IPs it seems.

Comment: Yeah, but how did you do this?  I've tried several iterations of iptables syntax, and none worked.

Comment: @pgoetz I used `ferm` for firewall config so the statement which excluded the `lo` interface was: `outerface ! lo MASQUERADE;`.

In an iptables world you can also use the exclamation mark to invert your selection of interfaces, outerfaces, IP ranges etc.

Comment: lol, thank you! That was exactly my issue, it was a head scratcher that.